# Connecting and using C libraries

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, lib

Есть проект на android на Java, нужно подключить сишную библиотеку.
Подключил c помощью градла директорию `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` 
Создал класс для работы с либой

```
 @SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
 public class MyNativeMethods {

static {

    System.loadLibrary("BlaBla");
}

public native void test_method(String text);

}
```

С NDK серьезно столкнулся только сейчас...
Может кто подскажет что я делаю не правильно и подскажет путь ?

Документацию и гайды от гугла сомтрел.
Куча информации в голове, а четкой структуры нету.
При вызове метода происходит ошибка инициализации.

```
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                            at com.google.MyNativeMethods.<clinit>(MyNativeMethods.java:21)
                                                                            at com.google.FooActivity.onStart(FooActivity.java:32)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

lib в формате (.а) а не (.so)

Comment: Стек-трейс покажите.

Comment: @post_zeew update

Answer (score 0):

А теперь собирай шаред-либу (.so), так как а-архивы нужны только для линковки. И проследи, чтобы твоя библиотека попала в финальную сборку. И чуточку больше сообщений о ошибках пости, там все описано прямым текстом.